What's going on with my bottom-left folder’s name and badge? Why are they shaking like this?
See this video, please.
iPhone 15 Plus. Started randomly today. Didn't do anything. Phone not jailbroken. Running iOS 17 (not the latest version of it, though). Haven't opened the apps in that folder for several days. Didn't update anything yesterday or today.

That is not a setting or tweak. That looks like it could be hardware. I would start with updating iOS then watch it for a while. If it’s always in the same area all the time, chances are you’ve got failing hardware; likely the LCD panel.
